# What is the point of a basic Riverpod Provider in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, riverpod

I'm fairly new to Flutter and am now implementing Riverpod. I've studied a number of guides and tutorials, and they all seem to start with the same simple example - either a basic provider which provides "Hello World", or an integer, as follows:

```
final countProvider = Provider<Int>((ref) => 0);

final hellowWorldProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => "Hello world");
```

There is then a Consumer object within a StatelessWidget which calls watch() this provider to get the value.

My question is, what is the point of this? Not a single one of the tutorials that I've found show a way of modifying the value returned by the provider, so it will always be the same. What advantage is there in using the provider here? Why call watch() on a value that doesn't change? You could just hard code the value in the Widget, or if that's frowned upon, use a constants file or equivalent.

Please tell me what I'm missing here, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 use cases.

***1. Knowing if a user is logged out***

A simple use-case of a basic `Provider` is knowing if the user is logged in without depending on a `userProvider` directly.

Take a look at this model and provider:

```
class UserModel {
  final String fullName;
  final String email;

  UserModel(this.fullName, this.email);
}

final userProvider = StateProvider<UserModel?>((ref) {
  return UserModel("Person User", "person@stackoverflow.com");
});

final isLoggedInProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) {
  bool isLoggedIn = ref.watch(userProvider) != null;
  return isLoggedIn;
});
```

Say we have a logout method that sets the `userProvider` state value to null:

```
void logout(WidgetRef ref) {
  ref.read(userProvider.state).state = null;
}
```

Immediately log out is called, every consumer listening to `isLoggedInProvider` would react to the "logged out" state of the user.

***2. Dependency Injection***

Say we have a basic `Provider` that provides a repository like so:

```
final dataRepositoryProvider = Provider<DataRepository>((ref) {
  return DataRepository();
});

class DataRepository {
  List<String> _data = [];
  List<String> getSortedData() {
    _data.sort();
    return _data;
  }
}
```

And there's a `StateNotifierProvider` that depends on `DataRepository` - If we don't want to keep creating new objects of `DataRepository`, it could be injected like so:

```
final dataStateNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider<DataStateNotifier, List<String>>((ref) {
  var repo = ref.read(dataRepositoryProvider);
  return DataStateNotifier(repo);
});

class DataStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<String>> {
  final DataRepository _dataRepository;
  DataStateNotifier(this._dataRepository) : super([]);

  void getData(){
    state = _dataRepository.getSortedData();
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting and more complex examples, I'll take some time to ensure I understand them properly. Am I still correct in thinking that in my simple Hello World example, these isn't actually a way to directly change the String?

Comment: Yes, you are...You don't reset values of basic `Provider`.

Comment: Of course. And I assume for more complex situations where you need to modify the state, this is where StateNotifier and StateNotifierProvider come in useful.